# Modeling IF transformers in PSpice

Tags: pspice, modeling

How can I create an "IF AMPLIFIER TRANSFORMERS" in PSpice?
Which one should I choose? "Forward" or "Two Winding"?

[image: Screenshot from PSpice]

And if there is no problem, just according to this site ([https://www.electronics-tutorials.com/filters/if-amplifier-transformers.htm#:~:text=IF%20amplifier%20transformers%20are%20simply,coupled%20by%20an%20active%20device.](https://www.electronics-tutorials.com/filters/if-amplifier-transformers.htm#:%7E:text=IF%20amplifier%20transformers%20are%20simply,coupled%20by%20an%20active%20device.)), tell me how much should I put the values of the inductor, resistance, and transformer ratio?

Circuit:

[image: schematic]

I need a "RED IF" in this circuit!

Input:

Carrier: 1.6 Vp-p | 200-400 kHz

Message: 0.3 Vp-p | 1 kHz

Comment: It depends on the circuit the transformer is used in (almost entirely). I.e. there is no generic standard.

Comment: Also, a lot of them have taps on the primary, secondary, or sometimes both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double_tuned IF transformers need to be sharp enough attenuation (Quality Factor) to adequately suppress equally_strong signals that are only 2_channel_spacing away.

WIth such attenuation of near_by stations, even city listening ot AM has some hope of succeeding.

Assume you want 30dB attenuation, double_tuned, for 20KHz carrier spacing
(2 of the standard USA spacing of 10KHz).

Comment: This does not answer OPs question.

Comment: Is it possible to use a transformer in the simulation only to apply the message and carrier signal to the modulator circuit? Only ordinary transformers!
You do not need to use a simulation or transformer that is close to reality!
Only displaying the output modulated waveform is important to me! Thank You.